# Why are questions with answers not deleteable?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-questions

My question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571410/what-is-the-point-of-get) has cost me firstly lots of rep and secondly my ability to ask questions. I therefore want to delete it but when I try it says: "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag for moderator attention instead." Why is this, and please can I delete it?

Comment: Because deletion also affects the reputation of those who answered your question, and because the content in the answers also counts for something.

Comment: Besides, deleting it would, as far as I gathered, rather exacerbate the question ban problem than mitigate it.

Comment: Note that deleting that question would only harm you more if you have a post-ban. You do absolutely not want to delete it. Furthermore, a post-ban is not caused by a single post. It will be the result of an average participation history. Therefore it will be wise to focus on all your questions, bad or good, and improve them as much as you can.

Comment: @Bart if i edit bad or downvoted questions, why would it make any difference? Nobody is looking at them anymore.

Comment: Editing those questions into shape would bump them to the front page (if not downvoted below -5 I think). If significantly improved it might well bring you extra upvotes. And don't focus only on downvoted material. Upvoted ones which you can make even better might help as well.

Comment: @Bart my question is -6. what to do? :/

Comment: Leave that one alone if you can't improve it. Focus on your other content.

Comment: That one question might have tipped you over the edge, but you have 8 deleted questions, which hurts you more. If you want, I can undelete those questions for you to edit into shape.

Comment: @BradLarson if I do will that reduce my rep? Rep is more important to me than asking questions

Comment: What are you going to do with rep if you can't participate on the site?

Comment: @Bart if I answer enough questions I might get to ask one again

Comment: You can try. I don't know the details of the ban mechanism, so I can't say if that's a wise route to take. If you're question-banned a focus on your questions might be more productive.

Comment: @BradLarson hell, undelete my questions. I guess I deserve it

Comment: @imulsion - I've undeleted the questions you deleted, plus two questions that were closed as duplicates, but I believe deleted prematurely by the community. That should help, but you might want to go back and clean some of those up, if you can.

Comment: @BradLarson I still have a question ban!!!!!!

Comment: @BradLarson can my account be reactivated? I am getting really sick of this site. At the moment, I have a problem that I really can't get my head round, meaning I now have to register with C++ forums. Hopefully they will be a little more accepting than this site.

Comment: @imulsion - Even moderators don't have the power to manually override the system. However, we might be able to manually disassociate heavily downvoted questions of yours from your account to get you above the ban threshold. You have a number of good questions, so if you decoupled a few of the bad ones, you should be in good shape. To do this, email the community representatives at team@stackexchange.com and point out the questions you'd like to have disassociated from your account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, deleting the question will make the qban problem *worse*. The question ban is based on how many downvoted/closed/deleted questions you have.

Secondly, a question with upvoted answers cannot be deleted because people have put effort into writing those answers (and have gotten rep from the answers, which will go away if you delete it). So, only mods/20k can delete these.

Comment: 20K+ users can also delete such questions, not only moderators.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: that too; I wasn't exactly sure of this. The only place I have 20k is MSO, and I mainly delete programming questions here :)

Comment: 10K+ users can delete too, but after the question has been closed for at least 48h.

Answer (score 6):

You *do not* want to delete the question. If you have a question ban now, deleting questions is only going to make it worse. It'll take more than *one* downvoted question for you to have received a question ban, if you are banned now *this question* was not the only reason for that ban.

Questions with more than one answer, or with one upvoted answer are not deletable by the owner to protect the content added by others from frivolous deletions. People have put effort and time into creating answers to your question and that counts for something, not to mention reputation gained from upvotes on their answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should flag your question and in a custom flag, request that the post be disassociated from your account.

- Deleting the post will nullify any effort made by other users to answer the question - we don't want that...
- Deleting the post might also delete some really great answers - we don't want that either (there's even [a badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) for answering a heavily down voted question with a great answer).